# Multiple windows withing C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I want my project to have two executable windows. Whether that results in two executable files, or if both windows are launched when the exe is double clicked doesn't matter.

I want to be able to close the first window and have the second window continue to run. opening up a new instance of the first window shouldn't effect the second window, and no more than 1 instance of the second window should be allowed to run at once.

Ideally I would like my project to have two executable files, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I don't want to make them separate projects, because they share a lot of the same methods and variables, as well as user settings, but I may have to if that's the only way.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Becuase they share so much I would suggest making 3 projects

- 1 for each of the windows
- 1 for the shared functionality.

This way, the shared functionality can be compiled into a separate DLL and can be used by both exe's

Comment: The windows are each in their own .cs file, and the shared functionality is in a separate .cs file as well.

How do I make it so that my project can execute both windows? Have to executable EXE's from the same project(with separate classes)? If I was going to create separate Visual Studio projects, how would I access the methods from the shared project?